# Boot up resolution error, How to fix?

Tags: grub2

Me, being horrendously new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, i have not the slightest clue what is wrong, except for the fact my resolution is smaller than it should be and the menu on the side is gone. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Press the `SUPER` key (`windows` key). Search for 'displays`. Open it (logo is a screen with a scale). Now, choose your resolution.

**UPDATE:**

It's possible that your GPU drivers are interfering; or that your hw isn't 3D-capable. Please post the result of the following command:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

**A. If you're using nVidia drivers:**

Run the following command to remove them, and reboot:

```
$sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
$sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates
$sudo apt-get remove nvidia-experimental-304
```

Or just open Synaptic and search for nvidia, delete everything that you see now.

Reboot the system. See if everything's working. Run this command to check if Unity-3D will work:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

Reboot again. Reinstall latest nVidia drivers:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

**B. If using AMD/ATI GPU drivers:**

Run the following command to remove them, and reboot:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge fglrx
```

Don't reinstall them as ATI cards currently don't support Unity-3D.

Comment: Problem is, ive already tried that. Both resolutions i had available both didn't show the menu

Comment: Run this command: `$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p ` and post the result.

Comment: Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0" 
GLX is not availible on the system

Comment: Are you using AMD/ATI or nVidia drivers?

Comment: Yes i am.
Im using an nVidia 7800GT. (I thought you were talking about my processor, whoops :P)

Comment: Check the 'update' and it'd work just fine. If the issue is solved, mark the question as 'solved' and upvote the answer ('up' orange arrow) & say that it worked (bottom links).